# CSS3 animations perform worse in a web browser control than IE10

Tags: html, css, windows-8, css-animations, internet-explorer-10

I made a new WPF project with only a web browser control in it. When I load a html page with CSS3 transformations in both the simple app and plain IE10 (both on windows 8, all versions), there is a vast different in performance. Inside the webbrowser control it is choppy, but in IE10 it is smooth.

Things I have tried:

- Installed a high end video card
- Added a `DWORD` value of `10001` for wpfapplication1.exe to the registry at `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`.  (we also set the value for the Wow6432 version of the same key)
- Set `FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING` to `1` for WpfApplication1.exe (e.g. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING`)
- Confirmed that both these new values were being read by my application using Process Monitor.

Does anyone know any more tricks to force a web browser control to behave like IE10? I know that there are a lot of FeatureControls that are turned on by default in IE but off in a web browser control, but it really doesn't look like any more affect animation performance.

Comment: This probably should be tagged silverlight (but I'm not sure I understand the question).

Comment: This has nothing to with Silverlight, the same behavior happens in an MFC .exe hosting a web browser control.

Comment: To be clearer: I got the idea for changing the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION from this post: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version